# pdi spoon ms-access concat

Tags: ms-access, integration, field, pentaho, concatenation

Suppose I have this table named table1:

```
| f1| f2   | 
--------------
| 1 | str1 |
| 1 | str2 |
| 2 | str3 |
| 3 | str4 |
| 3 | str5 |
```

I wanted to do something like:

```
Select f1, group_concat(f2) from table1
```

this is in mysql, I am working with ms-access! And get the result:

```
| 1 | str1,str2|
| 2 | str3     |
| 3 | str4,str5|
```

So I searched for a function in ms-access that would do the same and found it! xD

The problem is that everyday I have to download some database in `ms-access`, create the function to `concat` there, and then create a new table with those concated values.

I wanted to incorporate that process in the Pentaho Data Integration spoon transformations, that I use after all this work.

So what I want is a way to define a `ms-access` function in the PDI spoon, or some way to combine steps that would emulate the `group_concat` from mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple - Query from access, and use the "group by" step to do your group_concat - there is an option to concatenate fields separated by , or any string of your choice.

Dont forget that the stream must be sorted by whatever you're grouping by unless you use the memory group by step.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is you move your data in ms-access to mysql with the same structure (mysql DB structure = ms-access DB structure), then execute your "Select f1, group_concat(f2) from table1". For details follow this below steps :

1. Create transformation A to  move/transfer your ms-access data to mysql
2. Create transformation B to execute Select f1, group_concat(f2) from table1
3. Create job to execute transformation A and B (You must execute tranformation A before B)